# parse HTML Table in VBS

Tags: dom, vbscript, html-table

I try to get an HTML Table via HTML GET request, modify it, and PUT it back to the Website.

The HTML requests self are working fine.

my Problem is: If i parse the table via:

```
Dim oHF : Set oHF = CreateObject("HTMLFILE")
oHF.write "<html><body></body></html>"
oHF.body.innerHTML = "<p>WhatEver</p>"
```

Some characters such as """" and "/" are gone.
The result is, that my HTML PUT Request get a bad Response.

Here is my Table String:

```
<table class="wrapped"><colgroup><col /><col /><col /><col /><col /><col /><col /><col /></colgroup><tbody><tr><th>col1</th></tr><tr><td>data1</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

After the HTML parse the table String will look like this:
`<table class=wrapped><colgroup><col><col> ...`

Is there a Workaround, or any other Parser that i can use?

Thanks for the answers.

Comment: Quotes around attribute values and self-closing tags are optional in HTML, so that output is valid. Why do you get a bad response from your PUT? (I can't answer the actual question - how to get the HTMLDocument object to keep quotes and self-closing tags.)

Comment: @andrew because i want to Change a table via rest-api and this api Needs a json string filled with the html table WITH quotes and self closing tags =/